# Can OndoubleTapListener make a class with GestureListener?

Tags: android, android-studio, gesture, gesturelistener

```
package com.example.gestures;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;


import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.gesture.Gesture;
import android.view.GestureDetector;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import static android.view.GestureDetector.*;
import android.widget.TextView;

      public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnGestureListener.OnDoubleTapListener{
```

It is showing error on OnDoubleTapListener. I can't implement methods. Plz solve my problem.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer to @Sumit's aswer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
OnGestureListener.OnDoubleTapListener
```

to

```
GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener
```

Refer to docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener)

Comment: Error is removed but i can't implement method by pressing Alt+Enter not showing option here.

Comment: @HarnoorSingh make sure you are doing it correctly coz I have implemented in my Android Studio IDE correctly

Comment: It is showing implement method in abstract class not in same class.

Comment: This interface has only 3 methods

Comment: Make sure you are clear with the concepts of inheritance in java

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213394/discussion-between-harnoor-singh-and-sumit).